# Верстка списка HTML\CSS

Tags: html, css

Добрый день всем! Такая вот задача.
Сам я только начинаю осваивать Web-технологии, и пока что не особо понимаю как сверстать такую штуку http://www.promokodex.ru/kupon/kideria#code-85361
Нужно вывести список товаров примерно в таком виде как по ссылке.
Подскажите пожалуйста, как это сделать. Буду очень благодарен!
Заранее спасибо!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В чем собственно проблема?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ru" prefix="og:http://ogp.me/ns#">

<head>
  <title></title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <style>
    * {
      -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
      -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
      box-sizing: border-box;
    }
    * {
      outline: 0 !important;
    }
    article,
    aside,
    details,
    figcaption,
    figure,
    footer,
    header,
    hgroup,
    main,
    menu,
    nav,
    section,
    summary {
      display: block;
    }
    body {
      margin: 0;
    }
    html {
      font-family: sans-serif;
      -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;
      -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;
    }
    a {
      background-color: transparent;
    }
    *::before,
    *::after {
      -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
      -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
      box-sizing: border-box;
    }
    body {
      font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
      font-size: 14px;
      line-height: 1.4285;
      color: #333;
      background-color: #fff;
    }
    html {
      font-size: 10px;
      -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
    }
    p {
      margin: 0 0 10px;
    }
    a {
      color: #337ab7;
      text-decoration: none;
    }
    a,
    abbr,
    acronym,
    address,
    applet,
    article,
    aside,
    audio,
    b,
    big,
    blockquote,
    body,
    canvas,
    caption,
    center,
    cite,
    code,
    dd,
    del,
    details,
    dfn,
    div,
    dl,
    dt,
    em,
    embed,
    fieldset,
    figcaption,
    figure,
    footer,
    form,
    h1,
    h2,
    h3,
    h4,
    h5,
    h6,
    header,
    hgroup,
    html,
    i,
    iframe,
    img,
    ins,
    kbd,
    label,
    legend,
    li,
    mark,
    menu,
    nav,
    object,
    ol,
    output,
    p,
    pre,
    q,
    ruby,
    s,
    samp,
    section,
    small,
    span,
    strike,
    strong,
    sub,
    summary,
    sup,
    table,
    tbody,
    td,
    tfoot,
    th,
    thead,
    time,
    tr,
    tt,
    u,
    ul,
    var,
    video {
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
      border: 0;
      font: inherit;
      vertical-align: baseline;
    }
    .codes-list {
      width: 100%;
      overflow: hidden;
      float: left;
    }
    #page-providers-entry .main {
      background: url(/img/bg/item-divider.png) center top no-repeat;
      padding-top: 20px;
    }
    .col-xs-1,
    .col-sm-1,
    .col-md-1,
    .col-lg-1,
    .col-xs-2,
    .col-sm-2,
    .col-md-2,
    .col-lg-2,
    .col-xs-3,
    .col-sm-3,
    .col-md-3,
    .col-lg-3,
    .col-xs-4,
    .col-sm-4,
    .col-md-4,
    .col-lg-4,
    .col-xs-5,
    .col-sm-5,
    .col-md-5,
    .col-lg-5,
    .col-xs-6,
    .col-sm-6,
    .col-md-6,
    .col-lg-6,
    .col-xs-7,
    .col-sm-7,
    .col-md-7,
    .col-lg-7,
    .col-xs-8,
    .col-sm-8,
    .col-md-8,
    .col-lg-8,
    .col-xs-9,
    .col-sm-9,
    .col-md-9,
    .col-lg-9,
    .col-xs-10,
    .col-sm-10,
    .col-md-10,
    .col-lg-10,
    .col-xs-11,
    .col-sm-11,
    .col-md-11,
    .col-lg-11,
    .col-xs-12,
    .col-sm-12,
    .col-md-12,
    .col-lg-12 {
      position: relative;
      min-height: 1px;
      padding-left: 10px;
      padding-right: 10px;
    }
    .col-xs-1,
    .col-xs-2,
    .col-xs-3,
    .col-xs-4,
    .col-xs-5,
    .col-xs-6,
    .col-xs-7,
    .col-xs-8,
    .col-xs-9,
    .col-xs-10,
    .col-xs-11,
    .col-xs-12 {
      float: left;
    }
    .col-xs-12 {
      width: 100%;
    }
    /* @media all and (min-width:768px) */
    .col-sm-1,
    .col-sm-2,
    .col-sm-3,
    .col-sm-4,
    .col-sm-5,
    .col-sm-6,
    .col-sm-7,
    .col-sm-8,
    .col-sm-9,
    .col-sm-10,
    .col-sm-11,
    .col-sm-12 {
      float: left;
    }
    /* @media all and (min-width:768px) */
    .col-sm-8 {
      width: 66.66%;
    }
    /* @media all and (min-width:992px) */
    .col-md-1,
    .col-md-2,
    .col-md-3,
    .col-md-4,
    .col-md-5,
    .col-md-6,
    .col-md-7,
    .col-md-8,
    .col-md-9,
    .col-md-10,
    .col-md-11,
    .col-md-12 {
      float: left;
    }
    /* @media all and (min-width:992px) */
    .col-md-8 {
      width: 66.66%;
    }
    /* @media all and (min-width:1200px) */
    .col-lg-1,
    .col-lg-2,
    .col-lg-3,
    .col-lg-4,
    .col-lg-5,
    .col-lg-6,
    .col-lg-7,
    .col-lg-8,
    .col-lg-9,
    .col-lg-10,
    .col-lg-11,
    .col-lg-12 {
      float: left;
    }
    /* @media all and (min-width:1200px) */
    .col-lg-8 {
      width: 66.66%;
    }
    .row {
      margin-left: -10px;
      margin-right: -10px;
    }
    /* @media all and (min-width:1200px) */
    .container {
      width: 1000px;
    }
    .clearfix::before,
    .clearfix::after,
    .dl-horizontal dd::before,
    .dl-horizontal dd::after,
    .container::before,
    .container::after,
    .container-fluid::before,
    .container-fluid::after,
    .row::before,
    .row::after,
    .form-horizontal .form-group::before,
    .form-horizontal .form-group::after,
    .btn-toolbar::before,
    .btn-toolbar::after,
    .btn-group-vertical > .btn-group::before,
    .btn-group-vertical > .btn-group::after,
    .nav::before,
    .nav::after,
    .navbar::before,
    .navbar::after,
    .navbar-header::before,
    .navbar-header::after,
    .navbar-collapse::before,
    .navbar-collapse::after,
    .pager::before,
    .pager::after,
    .panel-body::before,
    .panel-body::after,
    .modal-footer::before,
    .modal-footer::after {
      content: " ";
      display: table;
    }
    .clearfix::after,
    .dl-horizontal dd::after,
    .container::after,
    .container-fluid::after,
    .row::after,
    .form-horizontal .form-group::after,
    .btn-toolbar::after,
    .btn-group-vertical > .btn-group::after,
    .nav::after,
    .navbar::after,
    .navbar-header::after,
    .navbar-collapse::after,
    .pager::after,
    .panel-body::after,
    .modal-footer::after {
      clear: both;
    }
    .container {
      margin-right: auto;
      margin-left: auto;
      padding-left: 10px;
      padding-right: 10px;
    }
    /* @media all and (min-width:768px) */
    .container {
      width: 740px;
    }
    /* @media all and (min-width:992px) */
    .container {
      width: 980px;
    }
    #footer,
    #header,
    #main {
      width: 100%;
      float: left;
    }
    body {
      line-height: 1;
      font-size: 10px;
      font-family: Arial, Tahoma, Verdana, sans-serif;
      background: url(http://www.promokodex.ru/img/bg/html-bg.gif) left top;
      position: relative;
    }
    .codes-list .item {
      background: url(http://www.promokodex.ru/img/bg/item-divider.png) center bottom no-repeat;
      clear: both;
      margin: 0 0 25px;
      padding: 5px 5px 17px;
      display: block;
      float: left;
      width: 100%;
    }
    .codes-list .discount-type {
      background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #fff 0, #ededeb 100%);
      border: 1px solid #d1d1d1;
      box-shadow: 0px 2px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
      float: left;
      height: 150px;
      margin: 0 20px 10px 0;
      padding: 10px;
      position: relative;
      text-shadow: 0px 1px 1px #fff;
      width: 150px;
    }
    .process-code {
      cursor: pointer;
    }
    .codes-list .discount-type .brd {
      border: 1px dashed #d4d4d4;
      height: 100%;
      width: 100%;
      overflow: hidden;
    }
    .codes-list .discount-type,
    .codes-list .discount-type .brd {
      border-radius: 6px;
      color: #1eafea;
      display: block;
      text-decoration: none;
    }
    .codes-list .share-code {
      clear: left;
      float: left;
      position: relative;
    }
    .codes-list .discount-description {
      overflow: hidden;
      padding-right: 30px;
    }
    .clear-both {
      clear: both;
    }
    .date {
      color: #adadad;
      font: 11px Verdana, Tahoma, sans-serif;
    }
    .codes-list .date {
      display: block;
      float: left;
      margin: 2px 0 4px;
    }
    .alphabet-selector a,
    .codes-list .title,
    .more_cat {
      display: block;
      text-decoration: none;
    }
    .codes-list .title {
      clear: both;
      color: #18a9f1;
      font-size: 16px;
      font-weight: 700;
    }
    .codes-list .code {
      margin: 4px 0 2px;
    }
    .text {
      max-width: 100%;
      overflow: hidden;
    }
    .text {
      color: #414141;
      font-size: 1.4em;
      line-height: 1.4;
    }
    .codes-list .text {
      color: #595959;
      font-size: 14px;
      padding: 10px 0 0;
    }
    .text ol,
    .text p,
    .text ul {
      padding: 0 0 10px;
    }
    .codes-list .show-code {
      background: url(http://www.promokodex.ru/img/bg/show-code-button.png) no-repeat;
      color: #fff;
      display: table;
      font-size: 18px;
      font-weight: 700;
      height: 54px;
      line-height: 53px;
      text-decoration: none;
      text-shadow: 0px 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
      width: 410px;
    }
    .codes-list .action.show-code {
      background: url(http://www.promokodex.ru/img/bg/action-active-bg.png) no-repeat;
    }
    .codes-list .code-wrapper {
      display: none;
    }
    .codes-list .show-code span {
      padding: 0 0 0 25px;
    }
    .codes-list .show-code .toggler {
      display: block;
    }
    .codes-list .action.show-code span,
    .codes-list .opened.show-code span {
      text-align: center;
      padding: 0;
    }
    #filters .filters-toggler,
    #filters .filters-toggler:hover,
    .codes-list .show-code span ins,
    .favorites-list .more:hover,
    .share-code .box .close,
    .share-code .clipboard {
      text-decoration: none;
    }
    .active-true.codes-list .show-code ins:first-child {
      display: none !important;
    }
    a {
      cursor: pointer;
    }
    .codes-list .share-code a.toggler {
      color: #747474;
      display: block;
      margin: 0 0 0 30px;
      overflow: hidden;
      font-size: 16px;
      padding: 2px 0 0;
      text-decoration: none;
    }
    .codes-list .share-code a.toggler ins {
      background: url(http://www.promokodex.ru/img/ico/share-code-icon.png) no-repeat;
      display: block;
      float: left;
      height: 22px;
      margin: -2px 5px 0 0;
      width: 22px;
    }
    .t,
    .tc {
      vertical-align: middle;
      height: 100%;
    }
    .t,
    .tc {
      text-align: center;
    }
    .t {
      display: table;
      width: 100%;
    }
    .tc {
      display: table-cell;
      width: 100%;
    }
    .codes-list .discount-type .type {
      display: block;
      font-size: 23px;
      line-height: 1.2;
      font-weight: 700 !important;
      margin: 0;
      font-family: HelveticaNeueCyrRoman;
      text-align: center;
      text-shadow: 0px 1px 1px #fff;
    }
    .codes-list .discount-type .value {
      display: block;
      font-size: 38px;
      font-weight: 700;
      line-height: 1;
      text-align: center;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body id="page-providers-entry" itemtype="http://schema.org/WebPage" itemscope="itemscope">
  <main id="main">
    <div class="container" xmlns:function="http://example.com">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-8 col-md-8 col-lg-8">
          <div class="main">
            <div class="codes-list codes-by-provider-active active-true">

              <div class="item last-true action-true iframe-true" id="code-87047" data-go="kideriaru/87047/">
                <div class="discount-type t-aktsiya c-protsenty x-true">
                  <div class="brd process-code" data-id="87047" data-go="http://www.promokodex.ru/go/87047"><span class="t"><span class="tc"><span class="type">скидка</span><span class="value">30%</span></span>
                    </span>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="share-code"><a class="toggler" href="#" data-id="87047" data-link="http://www.promokodex.ru/kupon/kideria#code-87047"><ins></ins>поделиться
  </a>
                </div>
                <div class="discount-description">
                  <span class="date">Промокод активен до&nbsp;30.06.2016</span><span class="title">Скидка 30% на товары для творчества!</span>
                  <div class="code">
                    <div class="process-code show-code action" data-id="87047" data-go="http://www.promokodex.ru/go/87047">
                      <span class="toggler"><ins>Акция закончилась</ins><ins>Открыть акцию</ins></span><span class="code-wrapper"><ins>Акция закончилась</ins><ins>Открыть акцию</ins></span>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="text ">
                    <p>Скидка на товары для творчества от Djeco, Crayola, DonerLand, Живой песок&nbsp;из раздела акции.</p>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="clear-both"></div>
              </div>

              <div class="item last-false action-true iframe-true" id="code-84808" data-go="kideriaru/84808/">
                <div class="discount-type t-aktsiya c-protsenty x-true">
                  <div class="brd process-code" data-id="84808" data-go="http://www.promokodex.ru/go/84808"><span class="t"><span class="tc"><span class="type">скидка</span><span class="value">30%</span></span>
                    </span>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="share-code"><a class="toggler" href="#" data-id="84808" data-link="http://www.promokodex.ru/kupon/kideria#code-84808"><ins></ins>поделиться
 </a>
                </div>
                <div class="discount-description">
                  <span class="date">Промокод активен до&nbsp;23.06.2016</span><span class="title">Скидка 30% на бутылочки и соски CHICCO!</span>
                  <div class="code">
                    <div class="process-code show-code action" data-id="84808" data-go="http://www.promokodex.ru/go/84808">
                      <span class="toggler"><ins>Акция закончилась</ins><ins>Открыть акцию</ins></span><span class="code-wrapper"><ins>Акция закончилась</ins><ins>Открыть акцию</ins></span>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="text ">
                    <p>Акция распространяется на определенную группу товаров.</p>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="clear-both"></div>
              </div>



            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </main>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Спасибо! Туплю.